# Issue trying to setup jest: application code compiles fine but test code doesn't

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to migrate to jest and I am facing typescript issues...

I have 3 tsconfig files:

- `tsconfig.json` (base config)
- `tsconfig.lib.json` (application config)
- `tsconfig.jest-spec.json` (jest-dedicated test config)

Please note that there are also karma/jasmine dedicated tsconfig files but those are irrelevant. I have separated the jest tests from the karma ones.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
     "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
…

}
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tmp"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.lib.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc/libs/xxx",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.ispec.ts",
    "**/*.uspec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.jest-spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc/libs/xxx",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.jest.ts",
    "**/*.jest-spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.ispec.ts",
    "**/*.uspec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Here is also my jest.config.js file:

```
const esModules = ['ng-inline-svg', 'ngx-bootstrap', 'html2pdf.js', 'ng-circle-progress'].join('|');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(jest-spec|jest).[jt]s'],
  rootDir: 'libs/xxx',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src/lib'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.base.setup.ts'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest-globals.js'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.jest-spec.json'
    }
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@XXX-ui/counterparty(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/lib/counterparty/src/$1",
```

With the above setup, I have to adapt the whole application code base, especially imports for example:

From:

```
import * as moment_ from 'moment'; const moment = moment_;
```

To:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Here is the error I get if I don't use the `transformIgnorePatterns` and I leave the `allowJs` and `esModuleInterop` to false:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.


    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:

     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.

     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.

     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:

    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    C:\git2\xxx-ui\node_modules\ng-inline-svg\lib\index.js:1

    export { InlineSVGConfig } from './inline-svg.config';

    ^^^^^^
```

I suspect there's a discrepancy between my application tsconfig and the test tsconfig and that is causing the behavior I see.

Ideally I would like to avoid having to change the application code base and adapt my test tsconfig.

Can someone please help?

**edit**: the above jest error seems to indicate that jest is trying to compile `node_modules` libraries (see: `ng-inline-svg`). How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: *the above jest error seems to indicate that jest is trying to compile node_modules libraries* - you're overriding `exclude`, it should have node_modules. Btw, `To:` is a correct way to import Moment and `From:` is not, so consider it making the app future-proof and compatible with TS module interop. Since you don't have Webpack in Jest setup you have limited ways in which modules can be abused (`import * as moment ..` is currently considered as such because it's really default export).

Comment: The problem seems to be specific to the package you're using. But it doesn't have untranspiled ES modules in this location, https://unpkg.com/browse/ng-inline-svg@7.0.1/lib/index.js . And the latest doesn't have `lib`, https://unpkg.com/browse/ng-inline-svg@10.1.0/ . So I'm not sure what's wrong with the one you have

Comment: Thanks for your comments @EstusFlask. I have added the `node_modules` entry to the `exclude` section. The issue remains... Can you explain further your second comment about the package please?

Comment: The package shouldn't have uncompiled ES module in main endpoint (\lib\index.js), see the links. It's unclear why the one you use has it. Please, clarify why it's so. The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you cannot provide it, at least try to provide all relevant data, i.e. package version. The goal is to make it to not have uncompiled ES module in main endpoint of the package. If you can solve this by upgrading ng-inline-svg then do this.

Comment: I have upgraded `ng-inline-svg` to latest version and I now get other errors with other packages... I am not sure why the production/application setup compiles fine but the test/jest setup doesn't... Any idea why that is?

Comment: Also why is jest going through `node_modules`?

Comment: Try to downgrade it instead possibly. As I mentioned, `lib\index.js` shouldn't have `export` keyword. The problem is that package version you use was built to be used with Angular and Webpack only, that's its fault. Such inconsistencies happen often with less popular third-party packages. Jest *doesn't* compile node_modules, unless you ask it to do that with custom transformIgnorePatterns, that's the reason. It does `require('ng-inline-svg')` for a file that has syntax error (`export` is invalid there). In production app you have Webpack that processes ES modules by magic. In Jest you don't

Comment: FWIW, you may want to stub all such third-party modules to make them not affect tests, otherwise unit tests become unpredictable because of extra moving parts, a lot of them expect real DOM and won't work as expected in fake DOM that Jest provides.

Comment: EstusFlask Thanks a lot for all the insightful and relevant information you provided!!